# Why don't we build a Mishkan today?

Tags: passover, beis-hamikdash, mishkan-tabernacle

I was just reading about [Mishkan Significance](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5675/mishkan-signifigance), the question there made the assertion that the Torah on the Mishkan is no longer relevant, reflecting the general opinion that we do not need the Mishkan today. That assertion was not challenged, so I'm basing my question on that, presuming that this is the prevailing wisdom.

Why would it, the Torah on the details of the Mishkan and it's construction, be irrelevant? Why don't we follow it today?

Given that the original Torah commandments of Sacrifices revolved around the Mishkan, and the commandment to build the Mishkan itself wasn't predicated on the later events that led to the building of the Beis Hamikdash, shouldn't these Torah commandments apply now, too?

Comment: According to some authorities (Ramban?) one is not permitted to attempt to rebuild the temple until Moshaich comes.

Comment: The answer is אסור במות which kicked in upon the temple's construction

Comment: @ tatpurusha: interesting that we wouldn't be permitted to rebuild the temple until moshiach comes but we won't be certain of who is moshiach until their actions reveal them as such. how would such a conflict be resolved?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45115/759

Answer (score -4):

I asked the same thing. There's no reason we shouldnt build a mishkan today. There would be no political problem with the dome of the rock having to be destroyed (bimhera viyamenu) and we would be able to offer sacrifices and truly celebrate the chagim and possibly reinstate nevua until one day we coild finally rebuild the beit mikdash. Were afraid. We're afraid to do hashems will

Comment: Where would you put the Mishkan?

Comment: No political problem with the dome of the rock being destroyed?

Comment: I think he meant no political problem COMPARED with rebuilding the beis hamikdash on the site of the dome of the rock.  I'd suggest a minor correction to wording to remove confusion.

Comment: Incorrect as only the correct location of the bais hamikdash could be used once the (first) bais hamikdash had been built. A mishkan would be a bama which is now asur. Note that Bar Kochva is supposed to have rebuilt the mizbeach on the correct place when he freed Yerushalayim during his revolt.