# A Tabernacle while waiting?

Tags: talmud-gemara, torah-study, beis-hamikdash, commentaries, mishkan-tabernacle

Before the Temple (Beit Hamikdash) there was the Tabernacle (Mishkan Hakodesh). Now there's no longer a Temple and people are waiting till the (3rd) Temple will be rebuild, why isn't there a Mishkan in the meanwhile? Is this because of the missing attributes?

Comment: There was no Tabernacle between the First Beit HaMikdash and the Second Beit HaMikdash.

Comment: Also sorta dupular http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45115/759